# Postman - submit token

Tags: rest, api, curl, postman

I'm new with Postman,(until today never used it)

I want this API request to run through Postman (pretty output)

```
curl -X GET  http://localhost/api/myapi/subnets/ --header "token: token"
```

Through Postman i can easily get this token:

```
http://localhost/api/myapi/user/
```

Output:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "token": "token",
        "expires": "2019-09-13 19:29:55"
    },
    "time": 0.013
}
```

But i don't know how to pass `--header "token:token"` part to Postman

[image]

[image]

I tried a couple of suggestion from Stack Overflow  but none seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header section you can add the header param you want:

[image]

just write in the "key" column.

The Authorization section is an easy way to add the common "Authorization" header. All others header should be added by "Headers" section.

The request in my image is the same of your curl command.

Answer (score 0):

Found it on this link: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-convert-cURL-code-to-Postman

```
http://localhost/api/myapi/subnets/?Authorization= token
```